# How to get phpspreadsheet to fit to page when there is extra space

Tags: phpspreadsheet

I have a excel sheet that i'm trying to convert into a pdf. However, whenever I try to use Mpdf, the pdf looks like this. 
[image]

I get a similar result when using Dompdf:

[image]

I've already tried using `setFitToPage(1)`,
`setFitToWidth(1)`,
`setFitToHeight(0)`, and
`setPaperSize(\PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet\Worksheet\PageSetup::PAPERSIZE_LETTER)`. Does this have to do more with the excel, or can something be done in phpspreadsheet?

Comment: Sometimes there are non visible Characters in a cell. You can try to delete a Colums F-K from your template.

Comment: I've tried that out, and you were right. Removing it got it to work. Thank you!

Comment: I have add an answer post. Feel free to check the correct answer button.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sometimes there are non visible Characters in a cell. You can try to delete a Colums F-K from your template.